# resetting powerpoint slide at hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, hyperlink

using a quiz question/answer set of slides.  I have animation on slides to make the answer appear.  I have hyperlinks that send me back to review the questions but when it jumps back, it doesn't reset the animation so it shows the question with the answer.  the jump back shows the question with the answer.

how do I reset the animation in a hyperlink situation?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than linking back to the current slide, add an identical slide just before it, remove whatever the animation would reveal, give it an automatic transition to the next slide after 0 seconds; now link to this new slide.

When you hit this slide either in the normal course of the slide show or by linking to it, it will jump to the next slide (the one with your animations) faster than the screen can refresh, so the transition will be invisible.

This takes advantage of an oddity of PPT's, that when you move forward to a slide with animations, the animations play, even if the slide has previously been visited. When you move backward to or link to a slide where the animations have played, they won't play again.